# Starling onClick method

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, onclick, touch-event, starling-framework

I'm using starling framework, to simulate onclick method I use this code:

```
if(e.getTouch(this).phase == TouchPhase.ENDED){
            //Some code
}
```

It's OK, but it also fires, if the mouse is not over the button anymore, however I'd like it to dispatch only if it's over. Is there any way to achieve this?
thanks

in the code, "this" is a Sprite, It's kinda irrelevant thougth

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://doc.starling-framework.org/core/starling/events/TouchEvent.html#interactsWith%28%29) the `interactsWith(target:DisplayObject)` method of the `TouchEvent` class should return true if the target is *currently* being touched. I have no way to test this theory, but the following should work:

```
if (e.getTouch(this).phase == TouchPhase.ENDED && e.interactsWith(this)) {
    //The touch ended on the same DisplayObject as it originated at
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this idea:

```
if ( e.getTouch( this ).phase == TouchPhase.ENDED ) {
    if ( this.hitTestPoint( stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY, true ) ) {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

Comment: this does the same what it did before. it does not give you the actual touch, it gives the touch, wich was dispatched when (I suppose) you hit the button (like onmousedown)

Comment: Edited the post to use current mouse position.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Starling framework; what I am trying to suggest is the idea of adding a second condition to verify that the mouse is indeed on top of the button since your problem is "it also fires, if the mouse is not over the button anymore..." Please treat this then as a pseudocode of sorts. Thanks for thinking it's a good idea. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be to use a starling.display.Button to do it. they dispatch TRIGGERED Events, which are basically what you want. The 'not so easy' way is to keep track of your touches, by replicating what is actually done in Button :

```
    private function onTouch(event:TouchEvent):void
    {
        var touch:Touch = event.getTouch(this);
        if (!mEnabled || touch == null) return;

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.BEGAN && !mIsDown)
        {
            //equivalent to MOUSE_DOWN
            mIsDown = true;
        }
        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.MOVED && mIsDown)
        {
            // reset button when user dragged too far away after pushing
            var buttonRect:Rectangle = getBounds(stage);
            if (touch.globalX < buttonRect.x - MAX_DRAG_DIST ||
                touch.globalY < buttonRect.y - MAX_DRAG_DIST ||
                touch.globalX > buttonRect.x + buttonRect.width + MAX_DRAG_DIST ||
                touch.globalY > buttonRect.y + buttonRect.height + MAX_DRAG_DIST)
            {
                mIsDown = false;
            }
        }
        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.ENDED && mIsDown)
        {
            mIsDown = false;
            //this is a click
            dispatchEventWith(Event.TRIGGERED, true);
        }
    }
```

you'l have to change the buttonRect code to reflect your sprite's shape, but basically here you are.

Comment: you could also add a timeout in the mouse_down part, so only "quickclicks" are checked. But if you are going this far I would recommend using Gestouch.